# Create "blank" admin page without having admin-bar/admin-menu for faster load

Tags: php, customization, wp-admin, import, bulk

I'd like to create a page in the WP Admin backend that is just "white", e.g. without the administration menu or the admin bar.

I am NOT looking to create an admin page without adding it to the menu; I'd like to create a page in the admin, where it is simply "white".

I need this because I need to run an import script, and it needs to load as fast as possible. The user would not need to use the admin/adminbar, and it would just slow the process down.

Comment: Why not set up a cron job that does the task? You could let the user manually trigger the cron to run with a cron plugin, and you wouldn't need to create a page at all.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with wp_ajax instead